# Running multiple iteration API calls using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I need to run 1000 API calls for 1000 different URI's. I tried to run 1000 different URI in one go as shown below but the API has a limit of 1000 lines. 
Is there a way to run this code 1000 times producing 1000 separate JSON files or in one JSON file without me having to run the URI with the powershell script indivdiually.

```
$access_token ="dfdfgdfgf45h5676rdffghfghfbazbfgjvdrtwsffrgr"
$LogPath ='C:\StackOVerflow'

$URI = 'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_80weqwepeopeoA'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_B0980kdfl;skfd'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Csdfsdfsjlksdc'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Tlksdjfalkjdff'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Fldkfjlsfjdfdl'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Fsdfsdfsdfsd34'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_G34gfgf4ffsdrf'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Haere34534fdgf'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Ifdl023lererew'
       'https://api.web.ser/audits/a_Afrererl45645w'

$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers |ConvertTo-Json| out-file "$LogPath\id_ExtractLogs$(((get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))).json"


$result
```

Comment: Use a `foreach()` loop to over each line one at a time, and in each iteration, call a custom function to run the operation you need that takes parameters you could use. If you need an example I'll post one as an answer

Comment: Invoke-webrequest might better help you in this!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an array of `uri` to the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet; they must be iterated.

Here's a working solution:

```
$uri = 'https://api.web.ser/audits'
$reportList = @(
    'a_80weqwepeopeoA'
    'a_B0980kdfl;skfd'
    # .. etc.
)

$token = 'secret'
$headers = @{ Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token" }}

$logPath = 'C:\StackOverflow'

foreach ($report in $reportList) {
    $stamp = Get-Date -Format FileDateTime
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri/$report" -OutFile "$logPath\id_$stamp.json" @headers
}
```

Comment: Much better, nice one

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1. I get an error:   " Invoke-RestMethod : {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"child \"auditId\" fails because [\"auditId\" must only contain alpha-numeric and underscore characters]","validation":{"source":"params","keys":["auditId"]}}At line:15 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri/$reportList" -OutFile "$logPath\id_$ ...."

Comment: @Djbril That's a problem on your end.  Your paths in the `uri` are incorrect.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible. There is an issue with writing out the file in json because when I take out " $logPath = 'C:\StackOverflow " and " $stamp = Get-Date -Format" FileDateTime and " -OutFile "$logPath\id_$stamp.json" I can see the results in the terminal.

Comment: @Djbril Use the `PassThru` parameter if you want the contents in the console *and* file.

Comment: TheIncorrigible1. I changed the code to     $stamp = Get-Date -Format FileDateTime
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri/$report" @headers -OutFile "$logPath\id_$stamp.json" Its now working perfectly. Could you change it so I can accept your answer.